# Какой оптимальный вариант для хранения данных в БД

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня есть база данных для блога в ней есть таблицы posts и comments.

У пользователей есть возможность оценить пост и комментарии к нему (рейтинг).

У меня есть два варианта:

1. Создать одну таблицу ratings и туда записывать все данные
2. Создать две таблицы для рейтинга постов (rating_posts) и комментариев (rating_comments)

Вопрос: Как правильно спроектировать таблицу для рейтинга в базе данных?

И я хотел бы попросить вас посоветовать мне хорошую книгу по проектированию баз данных.

1-й вариант

```
DataBase // ratings
id **Идентификатор**
users_id **Идентификатор пользователя**
type **Posts/Comments**
content_id **Идентификатор Posts/Comments**
rating **Like(1)/Dislike(0)**
created_at **Дата создания**
updated_at **Дата редактирования**
```

Comment: ну раз там будет храниться по сути одна и та же информация (вроде количества звезд), то бы выбрал 1 вариант.

Comment: Да я бы вообще делал одну таблицу, а не две. Коммент от поста ничем не отличается, кроме отсутствия родительского сообщения у поста. И соответственно тогда без вариантов - будет одна таблица рейтингов. Заодно - появится теоретическая возможность комментировать комменты.

Comment: В варианте 1 будет труднее наладить связи между таблицами (foreign key и всё такое), вариант 2 более естественнен для реляционной БД и всяких ORM. Хотя соглашусь с Akina в том плане, что можно подумать над объединением постов и комментов в одну таблицу, тогда и для рейтингов будет одна таблица

Comment: @Akina как ссылки проставлять? Прям внеш. ключи в схеме comment_id, post_id или object_id, object_type? Если первое, то смешение схемы, если второе, тогда зачем усложнять схему только ради двух сущностей. Ну и еще момент: постов то обычно не много и при выборке с join не надо комменты будет отсеивать базе.

Comment: Про "возможность комментировать комменты" тоже такая мысль была, значит таблицу comments можно также спроектировать как и ratings, так что бы были вложенные комментарии/рейтинг и не нужно плодить дополнительные таблицы, а в таком подходе могут быть подводные камни?

Comment: @tcpack4 *как ссылки проставлять?* ?? self-reference - самое обычное дело для хранения деревьев, каковым собственно описанная структура и является. *постов то обычно не много и при выборке с join не надо комменты будет отсеивать базе* Структура таблицы не ограничивается полями, есть ещё и индексы... с условием `WHERE parent_id IS NULL` запросы справляются легко и непринуждённо.

Comment: *а в таком подходе могут быть подводные камни?* Применительно к описанному кусочку предметной области - никаких.

Comment: @JonYanjoly Подводные камни с одной таблицей могут возникнуть при добавлении дополнительных параметров к посту — заголовок, раздельная нумерация, открытый/закрытый блог, проверки доступа и т.п. Если вдруг что-то подобное предвидится, то может оказаться проще реализовать две раздельные таблицы (но это требует детального изучения задачи)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, решил сделать по 1-му варианту, все рейтинги буду там, а обращаться буду по полю "тип записи"

Comment: @JonYanjoly но имейте в виду, что так вы не сможете прокинуть foreign keys

Comment: @Akina а, я понял вы и родительскую таблицу хотите объединить. ну такое себе, у поста обычно куча доп полей есть: title, slug, image, published которые комментам не нужны. а у комментов свои. понятное дело работать и так и так не будет ломаться по скорости. только я не вижу смысла на ровном месте добавлять условие вместо обращения в конкретную таблицу. постов может быть 100, а комментов x100

Comment: После всего прочитанного у меня получилась вот такая структура таблицы ratings. //
id **Идентификатор** //
users_id **Идентификатор пользователя** //
type **Posts/Comments** //
content_id **Идентификатор Posts/Comments** //
rating **Like(1)/Dislike(0)** //
created_at **Дата создания** //
updated_at **Дата редактирования** //

Comment: Что-то у вас не туда дело зашло, Почему про нормальные формы никто не вспомнил?